# Android library project fails to register to Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-library

I am writing an Android library project. I try to register to Google map and get the API key. I use my `certificate information`, meaning that I take a [`SHA1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) fingerprint from my library, and get the API key.

The problem is that I need to write this information in the **host application** manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY" />
```

This API key suits my library and not the host application.
When I run my library project like a separate application, it works properly

Does anyone has an idea how can I use my `api_key` as a library project?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API keys are bound to the package name of the application and the certificate used to sign it (you can use the same key for multiple applications, of course, but you must register each one individually in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)).

As far as I know, there is no option to provide the key in runtime either. While the now-deprecated V1 API did provide a [constructor supplying the key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#MapView%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29), the [new API](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html) does not.

Therefore, if what you want to do is distribute a "ready to use" library project with an included API key (yours) for any application, it looks like that's not possible. You need to tell your users to obtain a key, and then include the "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" entry in their AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: So what would be a good result? Asking for the host's API key while initializing the package?

Comment: @AdamMatan I don't think that's possible. Edited my answer a bit to make that clear.

Comment: @matiash if the host application will register in the developer consule and  include the "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" entry in their AndroidManifest.xml file. our library will succeed to use google maps?

Comment: @user3616237 Yes. The check is done "per application".

Answer (score 1):

1.-Put the activity implementing the MapView/FragmentMap into your library. Since the activity would be in a package registered in the Developers's console, it should work. You'll need to merge the manifests.

2.-Name the main package of the final app with the same name of the library's main package. Since the package name is used as a signature for the API key, it may work. You'll need to merge manifests.